# Cookie “pardot” has been rejected because it is already expired

Tags: firefox, cookies, salesforce, pardot

I’ve added pardot tracking script as specified here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318309&type=1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    piAId = '12345';
    piCId = '1234';
    piHostname = 'pi.pardot.com';
    (function() {
        function async_load(){
            var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + '.pardot.com/pd.js';
            var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
        }
        if(window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onload', async_load);
        }
        else {
            window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

This works perfectly on Chrome.

But, when I looked into console log of Mozilla Firefox browser, getting the error as :
`Cookie "pardot" has been rejected because it is already expired`.

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you're serving a [first-party cookie](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_admin_first_party_cookie_parent.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) (as opposed to the default third-party deployed with the app. Firefox, Safari and Chrome will all block third-party cookies soon.
2. Firefox needs to be set to "Accept cookies from sites" from Preferences.  Depending on how your browser is configured
3. If you've gone thru steps one and two without success, you can actually change the cookie duration in Pardot Settings. You can choose to [change a Pardot Cookie duration](https://forcery.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/How-to-adjust-Pardot-first-party-cookie-duration.png) anywhere from a few months to up to ten year.